# iOS Cognito error 13 on one device but success on another

Tags: ios, amazon-cognito

I am running into a strange problem where the user was able to log in previously and now getting error 13 - Temporary password has expired and must be reset by an administrator. However, switching to a different device using the app login succeeds. Any ideas what needs to be done to clear cache or keys or anything else that is needed?